# Elegant way to extract a tuple from list of tuples with minimum value of element

Tags: python, list, lambda, min

I am having list of tuple from which I want the tuple with the minimum value at index `1`. For example, if my list is like:

```
a =[('a', 2), ('ee', 3), ('mm', 4), ('x', 1)]
```

I want the returned tuple to be `('x', 1)`.

Currently I am using `sorted` function to get this result like:

```
min=sorted(a, key=lambda t: t[1])[0]
```

Is there better ways to do it? Maybe with `min` function?

Comment: that's a good solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use [**`min()`**](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) function with `key` parameter in order to find the tuple with minimum value in the list. There is no need to sort the list. Hence, your `min` call should be like:

```
>>> min(a, key=lambda t: t[1])
('x', 1)
```

Even better to use [**`operator.itemgetter()`**](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) instead of *lambda expression*; as *itemgetter* are comparatively faster. In this case, the call to `min` function should be like:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> min(a, key=itemgetter(1))
('x', 1)
```

Note: [**`min()`**](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) is a in-built function in Python. You should not be using it as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

```
min([x[::-1] for x in a])[::-1]
# ('x', 1)
```