# How to get the tuple having the minimum value in a certain item?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, min

```
results = [({'age': 1},      30), 
           ({'weight': 80},   5), 
           ({'label': 'abc'}, 7)]
```

As shown above, I have a list of tuples. Is there any elegant way to get the tuple whose has the smallest 2nd item?

More generally, if I need to get the tuple who has  the smallest `eval(2nd item)`? `eval` is a transformation function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `key` arg of `min` with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

results = [({'age': 1},      30), 
           ({'weight': 80},   5), 
           ({'label': 'abc'}, 7)]

print(min(results, key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Output:

```
({'weight': 80}, 5)
```

Comment: beautiful, as my second question, i guess it is just something like `min(results, key=lambda t: t[1]**2)`

Comment: You could also use a `lambda` function instead of `itemgetter` and avoid an import by replacing `itemgetter(1)` with `lambda x: x[1]`

Comment: thanks Jebby, I was just commenting the same:)

Comment: @Jebby Yeah, but it's less efficient. `itemgetter` is a little faster.

Comment: @Indominus Yeah, you can do `min(results, key=lambda t: yourfunc(t[1]))`. You define `yourfunc`.

Comment: @Tomothy32 The `timeit` module says that `lambda` without the import is .05 seconds faster on average with 10000 tests. Just running `timeit` on the import is consistently .03 seconds for me.

Comment: @Jebby You must've included the import with your timing. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41787974 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/17243620

Comment: @Tomothy32 Yes. You need the import for itemgetter, not for lambda.

Comment: @Jebby Yes, but the `import` is a one-time thing. If you are using `itemgetter` multiple times, for example in a `for` loop, it's worth it.

Comment: @Tomoth32 After another `timeit` test by only importing the module once, `itemgetter` was only faster than `lambda` once on average over 10000 runs consistently. Sorry if I'm sounding pedantic, this just intriuged me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187220/discussion-between-tomothy32-and-jebby).